# retaining the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, retain

I would like the state of the view in a class created to be retained while i process over the other modules of the application, is it possible in ARC environment.

In my opinion, the view gets released if i get into an another class. so whats the solution, let me to know in case you know.

Comment: Please do not tag apple automatic-reference-counting questions with [tag:arc]. Instead, use the [tag:automatic-ref-counting], as `arc` is scheduled to be disambiguated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137914/disambiguate-the-arc-tag

Answer (score 1):

Set the view as a `strong` property, then it will not be released

Answer (score 0):

To be technically correct, the view *might* be released if it's associated with the view controller that's not visible at the moment. It is by design and trying to prevent the view from being dealloc is just fighting the framework, which is not good for your health.

However, if you really want to do so, you can retain the view in `viewWillDisappear:` method of the controller. For ARC, it's just assigning the view to an ivar. Note that when the view controller appears again, new view will created and you also need to override 'loadView' to assign existing view to the view of the view controller.

Comment: i did the way, tia told, it works. Thanks to tia , and also can i retain the view even after the application gets quit?,or else can i store the view to any of container outside like plist something? i want the answer for this too.

Comment: You cannot retain the view after application gets quit, you can merely save its state and it must be done manually. For example, if you have a view with few UISwitch, you can save their states to a plist in `viewWillDisappear:` and load it in `viewDidLoad:`. This is not a trivial task as not every views are as simple as the example, so you might need to think if it's worth your effort.